# How to generate java pojos from Database at intellij Idea

Tags: database, intellij-idea, pojo

From a database connection at Intellij Idea I desire generate a Pojo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Create the database connection at intellij Idea
2. Do right click
3. Go to `Scripted Extensions`
4. Generate POJOS.groovy

[image]